# Can hydrogen alone be used as a fuel?

Tags: combustion, hydrogen, fuel

I have always thought that fuel such as petrol, diesel, etc.. are getting burnt to move the pistons in the car (I am not bringing physics). Why not hydrogen be used as a fuel but I know the incident about the Hindenburg disaster but the same thing could happen if the Hindenburg was filled with petrol. So both are combustible and that's what we want. Petrol and hydrogen do the same job what does he want?. When hydrogen is burnt there won't be any smoke so it saves the environment. PS: This is just to make this question a bit understandable I have mentioned the word "Alone" in the question.

Comment: Hydrogen-powered cars exist. The energy density of petrol is higher than hydrogen and hydrogen is more difficult to store safely which why we use petrol and diesel.

Comment: Hydrogen-powered cars exist?? I never knew about that @Waylander.

Comment: But @Waylander Hydrogen is abandoned around the world!

Comment: Hydrogen alone can't be used as a fuel, you need an oxidizer like Oxygen, or Nitrous Oxide. But, of course, you might've assumed it, and not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I will of course assumed it but anyways thanks @PrittBalagopal

Comment: Hydrogen isn't abandoned, it's still used a little, but it's **very** hard to store and carry around. Sometimes, the very fact that it's a ridiculously great fuel makes it hard to use, quite ironic.

Comment: But @PrittBalagopal why can't we store Hydrogen as CNG?

Comment: By the way, do check out: [Hydrogen as a fuel really worth it?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14853/hydrogen-as-a-fuel-really-worth-it?rq=1) The answers claim that hydrogen is hard to store in vessels as it's hard to leak.

Comment: Another advantage over petrol is that with hydrogen, the world probably won't have to prop up oil states anymore.

Comment: Hydrogen fits the definition of a fuel perfectly. Of course it can be used alone. Whether or not it's practical or better is the issue.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Your comment with "alone" only confused OP; fuel and oxidiser are different things, and are treated separately.

Comment: @Mithoron Probably, thanks for setting things straight now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydrogen fuel cells which produce electricity from hydrogen and oxygen are over a hundred years old
https://www.thoughto.com/hydrogen-fuel-cells1991799

The recently introduced Toyota Mirai runs off a hydrogen fuel cell.
www.toyota.co.uk/mirai  as does the Hyundai ix35 and Honda Clarity

There aren't very many hydrogen filling stations in the UK which rather limits its appeal

Comment: You should try to improve your answers: make links, elaborate, maybe add pictures and stuff. They seem rather comment-like.